# Xamarin UICollectionViewController to display 2 cells per row?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Now I need my custom cells to display only 2 per row, am attempting to create a shopping cart view !? 
should I change numberOfSections !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution by implementing the follow within the UICollectionViewSource :

```
[Export ("collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:"), CompilerGenerated]
public virtual CGSize GetSizeForItem (UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    return new CGSize (width, height);
}
```

this lets you control your cell width.